# Several themes for view's custom styles

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles

I have one app theme and many custom styles for different `View`.

For example, snippet of code:

```
<!-- styles.xml -->
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light" />

<style name="title">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">22sp</item>
    <item name="android:padding">10sp</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center_horizontal</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/background_all_screen</item>
</style>

<style name="label">
    <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_alignParentLeft">true</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">5dp</item>
</style>

<style name="button">
    <item name="android:layout_width">match_parent</item>
    <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
    <item name="android:layout_margin">2dp</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:background">@color/blue</item>
</style>
```

And now I want make many color themes for application. This is mean, that in different color themes custom `View` was in different colors.
For example, in one color theme button is blue, in another - red.

How can I implement this resources for easy change of theme? 
[There is a useful tutorial](http://www.hidroh.com/2015/02/25/support-multiple-themes-android-app-part-2/), but what about the custom styles for elements?

*UPDATE:*
I [try it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10295430/android-apply-a-theme-on-a-custom-item), but this is nor work:

```
<style name="Button.MyButton" parent="android:style/Widget.Button">
  <item name="android:background">@drawable/shape</item>
</style>

<style name ="Button.MyButton.Theme1">
   <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>

<style name ="Button.MyButton.Theme2">
   <item name="android:textColor">#FFFFFF</item>
</style>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/save_button" 
    android:layout_width="0px" 
    style="@style/Button.MyButton"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/save"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

[This is answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8632025/3194048) I just use attributes and after that I can use different colors in different themes.

```
<!-- values/attributes.xml -->
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <attr name="myCoolColor" format="color" />
</resources>

<!-- styles.xml, define myCoolColor for each theme -->

<style name="Theme.MyApp" parent="@style/Theme.Light">
   <item name="myCoolColor">#123456</item>
</style>

<style name="Theme.MyApp.Dark" parent="@style/Theme.Dark">
   <item name="myCoolColor">#654321</item>
</style>
```